# Checking for unique username with Jquery post

Tags: php, jquery, html

So I'm running a script from my page using the Jquery post wrapper, and in chrome debugger the below cases happening:-

```
1) if the username is taken i'm getting `"taken"` 

2) else it echo's nothing.
```

However, I cannot get to the **alert('im here');** line it seems that `if(data=="taken")` statement is never run or always evaluating to **false**, which is not the case. What am I doing wrong?

### Jquery

```
 var flag;
    $.post('welcome/check_username',{childname: $('#name').val()}, function(data){
    if(data=="taken")
            {
                alert('im here');
                 return flag = true;
                  //tell user that the username already exists
                  }else{
                   return flag = false;
                      //username doesn't exist, do what you need to do
                       }
                       });
```

### PHP

```
if ($this->Form_builder->check_unique_username($username, $childname))
{
     echo "taken";
}
```

---

Comment: add console.log(data); and check the value of data.

Comment: from where You want to check unique username? Jquery / PHP ?

Comment: console.log(data) is empty when username is unique otherwise it has "taken"

Comment: were do you define the php file to make the ajax call to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its always good to trim things. try

```
  if(data.trim()=="taken")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var flag;
var result = $.post('welcome/check_username',{childname: $('#name').val()});
result.done(function( data )
{
    if(data=="taken")
    {
        alert('im here');
        return flag = true;
        //tell user that the username already exists
    }else{
        return flag = false;
        //username doesn't exist, do what you need to do
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, here are the sections I would check:

1. On the PHP side, check whether the function is properly getting the proper values in $username and $password. You can do this by modifying the PHP file like this:

   ```
   if ($this->Form_builder->check_unique_username($username, $childname))
   {
    echo "taken";
   }
   else
   {
     echo $username." and ".$childname." is not taken";
   }
   ```

   1. Then on the jQuery side, before the if statement, do console.log(data) or alert(data) to see what is being returned. Perhaps, you are sending data by the POST method but the server side script expects the parameters via the GET method.